# Excel - I want to duplicate a value from one cell to another only if the first cell is changed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of values in Column D that I want to automatically update into Column E but only if the value in Column D is changed.  Otherwise I want the cell in Column E to be blank  - Is this possible??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If value in D1 is manually changed I want the new value copied to E1, otherwise E1 should be zero

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1715089/edit) to clarify it. It would also be helpful to know what you have tried so far and what the problem you encountered is

Comment: How you tackle something like that depends on what the purpose of such tracking is and what requirements/expectations are for it. For a start that would work "initially" for detecting a first change, I'd say that Column D is "current," and copy all values to another column ("G" for this example) that is "previous". In Column E you could then display the value that's in Column D, but only if it differs from the value in Column G (only populate if "current" and "previous" differ).

Comment: You should provide a sample about the values in Column D and E, the result you need.

Comment: @PrestonManess that would probably work, what would the formula look like for that in column E using your example where G is a copy of all values from Column D?

Comment: You can use the [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function. It would look something like this: `=IF(D2=G2,"",D2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of a problem with your problem statement. A cell only holds a single value and not any past values. Wanting to detect a cell "change" with a formula is impossible*, as you need to compare it to past values to know whether it has changed. And even if you could compare it to a past value, how far back should you look? What is the criteria for the cell in E to be blank? Essentially all cells in D have changed since starting from a blank workbook, so E should never be blank?

The answer is of course to have a reference point in time. As per the suggestion in the comments you can keep a record of past values in another column, but it is then up to the user to manually determine when to copy and paste those "past" values before making the changes in D - fixing the reference timestamp.

Now if you want, you could automate this "fixing" using VBA macros, e.g. update the reference column if you press a shortcut, or when you close the file, or at the end of a week/month/year etc. In VBA you could even add code that triggers right after you have edited a cell or range of cells, then reads the old value via the undo buffer, and stores that in the reference column. See here for the excruciating detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668410/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-cell-in-excel-vba

Ps.impossible*: Nothing is ever really impossible, but what is possible is rarely what you wanted anyway.

In Excel, there is a formula to determine what single cell has been editted last:

```
=CELL("address")
```

You can for instance say in E2:

```
=IF(CELL("address") = "$D$2", D2, "")
```

Which would only show the new value of D2 in E2 for as long as you don't update any other cells or cause a recalculation whilst another cell has been selected. Its not fool proof, but interesting. It effectively helps you fix the timestamp to only the last edit.